# Hover pseudoclass not working on a bootstrap navbar anchor tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"><!-- navbar begings -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="http://vetamuse.com">Manuel Stoilov</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="navAnchor" href="about.html">About |</a></li>
                <li><a class="navAnchor" href="contact.html">Contact |</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I try to change the "navAnchor" class to display a black color when I hover, it doesn't work. I've tried different ways to do it, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my css:

```
.navbar > .collapse > .nav > li > a:hover { /* hover is a pseudoclass */
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
li > .navAnchor:hover { /* hover is a pseudoclass */
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

### Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: To override bootstrap, use their exact selector `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, it changes the `a tag` link color.

```
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li > .navAnchor:hover { 
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You can even use pseudo `nth-child selector` to target them individually,

```
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li:nth-child(1) > .navAnchor:hover { 
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
.navbar-collapse > .nav > li:nth-child(2) > .navAnchor:hover { 
   color: pink; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Guess I had to be more specific with it and also target the navbar-collapse.

Comment: Welcome @ManuelStoilov yes just check your html code before applying css style to it. Using > selector which can directly style your child element, but before that you need to add all your parent > child > .....{css style}

Answer (score 1):

Are there styles overriding it? Perhaps try `color: black !important;` If that works, that means that something was overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
.nav li a:hover{
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .collapse .nav li a:hover { /* hover is a pseudoclass */
  color: black !important; 
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Please try like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.navbar .collapse > .nav > li > a:hover { /* hover is a pseudoclass */
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

instead of

```css
.navbar > .collapse > .nav > li > a:hover { /* hover is a pseudoclass */
   color: black; 
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The ">" behind .navbar adresses the direct child.